# $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n} \log\log{(\frac{1}{x})}dx =-\frac{\log(2)\log(2n^2)}{2n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Does anyone prove the following definite integral ?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n} \log\log{(\frac{1}{x})}dx =-\frac{\log2(\log2+2\log(n))}{2n}$$

Answer (score 3):

We know that the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s)$ satisfies

$$ \eta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x + 1} \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad \eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s). $$

Using this, we find that

1. With the substitution $x = e^{-t/n}$, the integral becomes
   $$ I := \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n} \log\log(1/x) \, dx = \left. \frac{(\Gamma(s)\eta(s))' - \eta(s)\log n}{n} \right|_{s=1}. $$
2. Using the Laurent expansion of $\zeta(s)$ at $s = 1$, we have
   $$ \Gamma(s)\eta(s) = \log 2 - \frac{\log^2 2}{2} (s-1) + \mathcal{O}(s-1)^2. $$

Putting these together, we obtain the following answer:

$$ I = - \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{\log^2 2}{2} + \log n \log 2 \right) = -\frac{\log 2 \log(2n^2)}{2n}. $$